# Removing space between recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have searched around and they all mention about changing the `layout_height` to `wrap_content` but mine is already in `wrap_content`. I really can't identify any error. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbfMA.jpg)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.fyp.ipptapp.UI.StandardFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Age" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Gender" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_Age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:dropDownWidth="50dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_Gender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:dropDownWidth="50dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Voc" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Pop Gp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_Voc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:dropDownWidth="200dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_PopGp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:dropDownWidth="120dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/test"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Exemption" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/pushUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Push Up" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sitUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sit Up" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is this your layout for items (of recyclerview)? I think not. I would suggest go to the item's layout and use wrap_content on it instead, make sure to add `wrap_content` and make sure height, width, padding and margins are all correctly set for each and every view.

Comment: in your recyclerView item.xml make it wrap_content

Comment: post your adapter xml code

Comment: post you adapter item.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter xml parent layout height might be set to match_parent. Check it once

Answer (score 1):

In your item.xml(or where you have the structure for each item in recycler) check whether the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` like this.

Something like this :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

This will set the height and width according to the content within the item.
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

give some top margin to your layout.

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for the wrong xml file, add you inside item xml the one used at your `Adapter` not the `RecyclerView` one

Answer (score 0):

I think @MinnuKaAnae has answered the question, but I still want to use some layout UIs to show the answer. I simulate the issue on my side.

Obviously, the owner provided the wrong layout file, we need the item layout.

[image: error layout]

[image: correct layout]